# Why we must use magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping

Our company make shopping web site for customers and we want sell magento more expensive than woocomerce plugin of wordpress but there is a question "Why some one must pay more for magento?"
I know magento has very features but many free plugin exist for wordpress to make your website a good shopping site, please answer me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Question is answered, so don't close it. It is useful.

Comment: Yes, this question is broad and it might be opinion based, but it is important to answer and if you ask me totally in the scope of this side. What are the pros to use magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See It's depend on your Client Requirements.

If you are using Magento As E-commerce Framework then It's Free available same as woocomerce.

Magento Provide Three Edition so user can select and invest money as per his need.

1. [Magento Community Edition (FREE)](http://magento.com/products/overview#community)
2. [Magento Enterprise Edition (PAID)](http://enterprise.magento.com/)
3. [Magento Go(PAID) & provide support form Magento.](http://go.magento.com/) It Will Magento Go
   is Shutting Down on February 1, 2015

More Things which More Provide by Magento.

**1.Product Scalability.**

**2.The Most Important Security.**

**3.Magento Product Structure.**

**4.Extensible Your Extension.**

**5.MVC Structure <strike>based on Zend Framework.</strike>**

**6.Using More then 12 Design Patterns.**

Etc.

Let me know If you want to know more then About this.

*Edit: Neither the Views, controllers, nor the models are based on Zend_Framework. Zend_Cache is used, Zend_Db is used to save data, Zend_Locale, Zend_Mail, Zend_Currency and maybe some others are used. But I prefer to talk about components, than a framework. Magento is a framework which uses Zend components. It is not based on Zend Framework.*

Comment: I agree with you but customers dont want be involved with complexity of platform they just want a shopping site, all thing I've learned first we must know what he/she want and dependent on that request using right platform, am I right?

Comment: As I mention above its depends on client requirement